# Which is better convention among what the delegate method with class prefix or without prefix?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been agonizing over which convention is better when deciding a name of delegates of any classes I make. I usually add the application prefix to the head of methods as follows:

```
@interface HKKHelloWorld <NSObject>
...
@end

@protocol HKKHelloWorldDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)HKKHelloWorld:(HKKHelloWorld *)helloworld didFinishWorkWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end
```

In recent, I fall in one decision problem whether adding a prefix is good convention or not.
I believe people in StackOverflow is able to give me advice to make a better convention.

In short,
Which is better convention for a delegate of a class?

```
- (void)HKKHelloWorld:(HKKHelloWorld *)helloworld didFinishWorkWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

or

```
- (void)helloWorld:(HKKHelloWorld *)helloworld didFinishWorkWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use a prefix when your name might clash with other names. That means class names, which are all in one namespace, methods and categories that you add *to someone else's class*, and protocols.

Methods inside your own class are in their own namespace and don't require a prefix. It should be left off there.

Answer (score 3):

Both are syntactically correct but  2nd one is better,

```
- (void)helloWorld:(HKKHelloWorld *)helloworld didFinishWorkWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

above signature is look like same cocoa objective-C coding standard. See this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if one way is fundamentally better than the other, but prefixes can sometimes help a lot with Xcode's autocompletion.